# c# - Multiple panel form - ComboBox handler stops working when going to next panel and back to previous

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, panel

I created a multiple panel form using the Visual Studios Designer. The form is used to save Items to a database. The user adds information about the item in the first form then selects next to add pictures to the item. Different items have different numbers of pictures associated with them.

The transitions of the panels are as follows:

- Panel1 <--> Panel2a
- Panel1 <--> Panel2b
- Panel1 <--> Panel2c
- Panel1 <--> Panel2d

So for any given item, there are two panels to fill out. There are 4 versions of the second panel which determines how many picture boxes and "Browse" buttons there are.

A ComboBox on panel1 determines which version of panel2 is selected. A "next" button is used to move on to panel2 and a "previous" button switches back to panel1.

The code is as follows:

```
public partial class formAddItem : Form
{
    // To browse for images
    OpenFileDialog mImageBrowse = new OpenFileDialog();

    // store image paths
    string mImagePath1 = null;
    string mImagePath2 = null;


    // Constructor
    public formAddItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmAddItem_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Retrieve list of items from database, store in dataset
        // ...


        // List to use as DataSource
        List<string> listItemType = new List<string>();

        // Add items from dataset to a list and alter string for readability
        foreach (ITEM_TYPERow itemTypeRow in mDataSet.ITEM_TYPE)
        {
            listItemType.Add("ITEM_" + itemTypeRow[0]);
        }

        comboItemType.DataSource = listItemType;

        // set up current state
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel1.BringToFront();
        panel1.Focus();
        btnNext.Enabled = true;
        btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Next panel depends on item type selection
        string itemTypeSelection = comboItemType.Text;

        switch (elementTypeSelection)
        {
            case "ITEM_A":
                panel2A.Visible = true;
                panel2A.BringToFront();
                panel2A.Focus();
                break;
            case "ITEM_B":
                panel2B.Visible = true;
                panel2B.BringToFront();
                panel2B.Focus();
                break;
            case "ITEM_C":
                panel2C.Visible = true;
                panel2C.BringToFront();
                panel2C.Focus();
                break;
            case "ITEM_D":
                panel2D.Visible = true;
                panel2D.BringToFront();
                panel2D.Focus();
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        // Set current state
        btnNext.Enabled = false;
        btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
        btnNext.Enabled = true;
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel1.BringToFront();
        panel1.Focus();

    }

    private void btnItemA1Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set filter
        mImageBrowse.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png";
        mImageBrowse.FilterIndex = 1;

        DialogResult userCickedOk = mImageBrowse.ShowDialog();

        if (userCickedOk == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            mImagePath1 = mImageBrowse.SafeFileName;
            pictureBoxItemA1.Image = new Bitmap(mImageBrowse.FileName);
        }


    }


    private void btnItemA2Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set filter
        mImageBrowse.Filter = "png files (*.png)|*.png";
        mImageBrowse.FilterIndex = 1;

        DialogResult userCickedOk = mImageBrowse.ShowDialog();

        if (userCickedOk == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            mImagePath2 = mImageBrowse.SafeFileName;
            pictureBoxItemA2.Image = new Bitmap(mImageBrowse.FileName);
        }


    }

    // Resets image stuff when a new item type is selected
    private void comboItemType_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear images and image paths
            mImagePath1 = null;
            mImagePath2 = null;
            ...

            pictureBoxItemA1.InitialImage = null;
            pictureBoxItemA2.InitialImage = null;
            ...

        }
}
```

The `comboItemType_SelectionChangeCommitted()` seems to work when I press 'next' and then 'previous' if I don't browse for an image. But as soon as I browse, things stop working.

There are some other things going on but I am hoping they aren't relevant to my problem

Answer (score 1):

Look at changes I made to method below.  Button Next should display next panel (not current).

```
        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Next panel depends on item type selection
            string itemTypeSelection = comboItemType.Text;

            switch (elementTypeSelection)
            {
                case "ITEM_A":
                    panel2B.Visible = true;
                    panel2B.BringToFront();
                    panel2B.Focus();
                    elementTypeSelection = "ITEM_B";
                    break;
                case "ITEM_B":
                    panel2C.Visible = true;
                    panel2C.BringToFront();
                    panel2C.Focus();
                    elementTypeSelection = "ITEM_C";
                    break;
                case "ITEM_C":
                    panel2D.Visible = true;
                    panel2D.BringToFront();
                    panel2D.Focus();
                    elementTypeSelection = "ITEM_D";
                    btnNext.Enabled = false;
                    break;
                case "ITEM_D":
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }

        }
```

Comment: The item is selected on panel1. Then panel2 is chosen based on the current selection. The program goes to the correct panel, but when going back to panel one, the comboBox handler no longer works when comboBoxType is changed by the user. It chooses only one value of panel2 to go to, it doesn't cycle through them.

Comment: The btnPrevious_Click should look like the btnNext_Click but instead of going A, B, C, D should go D, C, B, A.

Comment: Why are you using SelectionChangeCommitted instead of SelectionChange? Read documentation.

Comment: You don't understand the problem. It never changes from A to B to C to D or any combination. It only ever changes from Panel1 to Panel2. It just depends which Panel2. I can't tell if you are trolling or just not reading the problem.

Comment: The main reason I don't use SelectionChange is because it is not a ComboBox Event. SelectionChangeCommitted only changes the value when the user selects a new value from the ComboBox. Given that the value is only ever changed by the user and never programmatically, this seems to be the correct choice. You are telling me to read the documentation and you clearly haven't even read the problem. Perhaps you should think twice before offering such advice.

Comment: Use either SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedValueChanged (not Committed which occurs after the click event).  The committed will have the old value in the Combobox and not the new value.  The Previous click event should look like the Next.